# Проблема с bash скриптом

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Есть вот такой скрипт:

```
for file in `find . -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.png" -or -iname "*.jpeg"`;do
  ext=${file##*.}
  if [ -n "$ext" ]; then
    if [ "$ext" = "jpg" ]; then
      echo "optimizing ${file} as jpeg file with jpegtran"
      jpegtran -copy none -optimize -perfect -outfile temp_abracadabra_filename.jpg $file 
      mv -f temp_abracadabra_filename.jpg $file;
    fi
    if [ "$ext" = "jpeg" ]; then
      echo "optimizing ${file} as jpeg file with jpegtran"
      jpegtran -copy none -optimize -perfect -outfile temp_abracadabra_filename.jpeg $file
      mv -f temp_abracadabra_filename.jpeg $file;
    fi
    if [ "$ext" = "png" ]; then
      echo "optimizing ${file} as png file with pngcrush"
      pngcrush -rem alla -reduce -brute "$file" temp_abracadabra_filename.png;
      mv -f temp_abracadabra_filename.png $file;
    fi
  fi
done;
```

При запуске выдает:

```
./optimzie-image 
./optimzie-image: строка 3: ошибка синтаксиса около неожиданной лексемы `then'
./optimzie-image: строка 3: `  if [ -n "$ext" ]; then'
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может,

    #!/bin/bash

в начало скрипта добавить?

Comment: аналогично
sudo ./optimzie-image 
./optimzie-image: строка 5: ошибка синтаксиса около неожиданной лексемы `then'
./optimzie-image: строка 5: `  if [ -n "$ext" ]; then'


os ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Проблема, я думаю, в банальном CR+LF.

Comment: Через http://www.shellcheck.net/ прогонял?

Answer (score 1):

Выполните с  **#!/bin/bash +x**
Будет понятней что происходит.